# SupportMapFragment getting corrupted when returning to activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-support-library

So I'm running into a very weird issue. I have a SupportMapFragment inside a fragment inside an activity with a DrawerLayout as the root layout. Everything works fine, except sometimes (seems to happen more when the phone is performing worse, i.e. is less responsive) , when I return to the root activity with the drawer layout via a finish() call to a subsequent activity, I get a very weird corrupted map that bleeds into all the other elements, including the status bar and even into the on-screen navigation buttons. Attached is a picture of this phenomena:

[image: Messed up screen]

Has anyone ever seen something like this? I don't get any error output in the log and all the code seems to run normally. I'm not sure how to debug something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to destroy or remove the fragment in onDestroy of Activity.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Try to browse the Q&A of map Sdk.